# How do you color/customize the UIImagePickerController's Navigation Bar?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

What is the correct way to color the UIImagePickerController's nav bar?

I merely tried to see the background color but I'm getting a faded color as seen in the image below; as if some view is obstructing it.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = type
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
picker.delegate = self
picker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

[image]

It appears to have some view obscuring the redColor():

```
(lldb) po picker.navigationBar.subviews
2 values
 {
  [0] = 0x00007fe7bb52a890
  [1] = 0x00007fe7bb52b670
}
```

What is the correct way to create a solid color for the Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 58):

**Updated for Swift 4.2**

For completeness, I'll add full color customization setup:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue // Background color
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .white // Cancel button ~ any UITabBarButton items
imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
] // Title color
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: i tried you code it is working fine but cancel button is not showing

Comment: This seems to be no longer working in iOS 13 -- the title, background and button colors are all the system colors. In iOS 13 the only way I could change the image picker navigation bar colors is via UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white etc. However, this isn't an ideal solution as it changes it for all the navigation bars.

Comment: tomblah's comment is still applicable in iOS 14 with the PHPickerViewController. I just make sure to set the tint color back to its previous value after dismissing the picker. `let startingColor = UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor; UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white` and then on dismiss `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = startingColor`

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
picker.navigationBar.translucent = false
picker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .redColor()
```

Instead of

```
picker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

If you want translucent effects, leave `translucent = true` as default.

Answer (score 10):

Here the right solution code in Objective-C. Might be useful.

```
imagePickerController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
imagePickerController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.147 green:0.413 blue:0.737 alpha:1];
imagePickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imagePickerController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift = IOS 8 || 9**

Just put this method

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) 
{
     imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .whiteColor()
     imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()
     ]

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5 / IOS 13**

I have found this solution:

```
let barApperance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
barApperance.tintColor = .systemBlue
```

just put it where you create the UIImagePickerController()

Comment: Thanks this worked for me with SwiftUI and custom navigation. Otherwise, in the light mode with white titles Add and Cancel buttons were not visible at all.

Comment: will this have impact at other places? If we have custom styles used in different view controllers for navigationBar

Answer (score 3):

For Swift, IOS 8-10 
As rintaro mentioned, I think the main issue here is changing the default translucent property of the picker navigationBar:

`picker.navigationBar.translucent = false`

This will cause the the navigation bar to use the UINavigationBar appearance if you set this somewhere in your app.

If you need another color you can use
`picker.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.someColor`

Answer (score 0):

> `UIImagePickerController` is a `UINavigationController`. It can be
>   styled as the same way the `UINavigationController` get styled.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [UIColor whiteColor], nil]];
```

This works for me on iOS 14. Nothing else works.