# How to change UIStatusBarStyle text color of a UIImagePickerController view

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

Trying to change `UIStatusBarStyle` of `UIImagePickerController` text color. Tried the following:

```
imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .darkGray
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011882/8071224) answer displays that even the carrier logo and `UIStatusBarStyle` also changes it color as specified. But it is not changing. Is there any other thing that could be tried to make the `UIStatusBarStyle` text color change in the `UIImagePicker`?

Tried the following code which is working for other `UIViewController`s

```
imagePicker.preferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
imagePicker.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

But not working.. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my code - a simple subclass of UIImagePIckerController.

```
public class ImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override public var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

=======
 Add UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to your

## @interface yourController ()<>

=======

## imagePickerController.delegate = self;

=======

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}

======